# hadoop jar command points to local filesystem

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I have a valid jar which is running perfectly on another system running the same version of hadoop i.e hadoop-1.2.1 with the same settings.

I am able to put the jar file in the hdfs filesystem and create input,output directories.

But when I use the command 'hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar classname(main method) input output' it throws 'Invalid jar' error. After searching for the possible solutions for a long time I found out that the command is searching for the jar in local filesystem instead of searching in the hdfs.

Even I tried adding scheme to the command as:
hadoop jar hdfs://HelloWorld.jar classname(main method) input output

What are the possible solutions to this?

P.S: I am able to run the hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar using 'hadoop jar' when my PWD is /home/user/hadoop-1.2.1 which is in my local filesystem

Comment: HelloWorld.jar stays in local system not in HDFS - Why are you storing it in HDFS?

Comment: @JtheRocker Can you point to some documentation which says `hadoop jar` picks the jar from the local system? I always load my jar on hdfs and run,it works fine. But I have the same path for the jar on my local path too.So it might be possible it is picking up the local one and not teh one on hdfs (as i assumed)

Comment: i tried everything guys...please help, I am stuck for a long tym now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hadoop jar`  only runs jar files that you can access locally<sup>1</sup>.  Just for the sake of curiosity - here is the relevant source that looks for the jar in the `hadoop jar` command.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
  String usage = "RunJar jarFile [mainClass] args...";

  if (args.length < 1) {
    System.err.println(usage);
    System.exit(-1);
  }

  int firstArg = 0;
  String fileName = args[firstArg++];
  File file = new File(fileName);
  if (!file.exists() || !file.isFile()) {
    System.err.println("Not a valid JAR: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    System.exit(-1);
  }
  ...
}
```

---

**<sup>1</sup>**  This is true for every Hadoop version I've come accross.  Your results may vary.

Comment: Yes i have seen this code. But the hadoop-1.2.1 which runs perfectly in another system , picks it up from the hdfs not from the local file system. 'hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar ...' is picking it up from /user/username which is the hdfs home but in my system the same command is searching for the jar in /home/username which is my current working directory.

Comment: Interesting. I'm dumbstruck now. But how? I'm curious too.

Comment: @user2672952 What other system is this?

Comment: The other system is also running hadoop-1.2.1 in pseudo-distributed mode with the jar in /user/username, inputdir as /user/username/input and outputdir as /user/username/output in hdfs

Comment: How did you call it on the command line and can you verify that you didn't accidentally create a `/user/username/` directory on your local file system?

Comment: I use the command 'hadoop dfs -put HelloWorld.jar .' which puts the jar in /user/username/ and likewise I have created the input and output directories using 'hadoop dfs -mkdir input' and 'hadoop dfs -mkdir output'. Inside the input directory I have the data file on which I want to perform mapreduce.

Comment: hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar org.myClass input output

Comment: And you're *positive* that `HelloWorld.jar` wasn't in the same directory you ran the command from?

Comment: See this, hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar mypack.myclass input output, isnt the jar,int input dir, output dir supposed to be in the same filesystem?? I am sure all three were on hdfs..

Comment: No.  The jar is local and gets distributed out to the applicable map/reduce nodes at run time.  Input/output directories are in HDFS.

Comment: I have tried putting the jar in the local filesystem's pwd but then it asks for the command line arguments missing.. i.e the input and output directories were not specified..

Comment: That should be in another question then

Comment: @climbage im running into same kind of problem and i have the administrative user by the name of user, could that be the cause of it?

Answer (score 1):

This code in my $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop script

```
'elif [ "$COMMAND" = "jar" ] ; then
CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar'
```

says, it points to **RunJar** class.

And, in the RunJar you have this,

```
/** Run a Hadoop job jar.  If the main class is not in the jar's manifest,
   * then it must be provided on the command line. */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String usage = "RunJar jarFile [mainClass] args...";

    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.err.println(usage);
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    int firstArg = 0;
    String fileName = args[firstArg++];
    File file = new File(fileName);
    String mainClassName = null;

    JarFile jarFile;
    try {
      jarFile = new JarFile(fileName);
    } catch(IOException io) {
      throw new IOException("Error opening job jar: " + fileName)
        .initCause(io);
    }

    ------ Other code -------
}
```

So, I'm not sure if  `File file = new File(fileName);` can actually point to a HDFS path?

**May be MapR distribution of Hadoop could do that.**

Answer (score 0):

Probably, It is too late to reply to this discussion though I did not see any accepted answer so thought of replying to this. Today, I faced the same problem and finally after effort of couple of hours, I am able to resolve it. I found two reasons for the problem of "Not a valid Jar".

1. When we refer to Jar from HDFS, it gives this error. I changed the reference to jar file in local file system and it worked properly. What I understood is that It is not required to put Jar file in HDFS.
   'hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar (Refer from your local file system) classname(main method) input output'
2. When you create the Jar file and define Main-Class while creating the Jar file then you don't need to define classname in the command.

'hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar classname(main method-This is not required if you have already defined Main-Class while jar file creation) input output'

Following will be the command:
'hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar input output'